# Why do iperf3 and tcp_probe report different congestion windows?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control, iperf

I am running a simple experiment with multiple `iperf3` senders on different servers, sending `TCP` traffic to a single receiver on another server.

`iperf3` reports the congestion window (`Cwnd`) every 0.1 seconds during this experiment (in KBytes). I also log the output from the `tcp_probe` kernel module during the experiment, which shows the congestion window every time it changes (in segments). I multiply the `tcp_probe-reported` congestion windows by 1500 (the MTU size) to get the congestion window in bytes. I expected the congestion windows to match, but I found that the congestion windows reported by iperf3 are about 94% of the size of those reported by `tcp_probe`. Once corrected by this multiplicative factor, they agree perfectly. Why does this occur? Which one is right?

The commands I run are:

```
iperf3 -c <dst_ip> -p <port> -i 0.1 -t 30

insmod tcp_probe.ko
```

I tried looking through the source code for both [iperf3](https://github.com/esnet/iperf) and [tcp_probe](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.c), but didn't see anything fishy.

Comment: You're including the IP and TCP headers when you multiply by the entire MTU. Try multiplying by 1460.

Comment: @EJP To account for the 94% I would have to multiply by 1410 instead of 1460 or 1500. I can't think of any reason why 1410 would make sense.